# Grafana "Data source connected, but no labels received. Verify that Loki and Promtail is configured properly."

Tags: grafana, loki

I'm trying to install loki so that I can read logs on Grafana, but I keep receiving `Data source connected, but no labels received. Verify that Loki and Promtail is configured properly.` (nothing from the logs).

I'm using docker images for each service (grafana, loki, promtail) on a Raspberry Pi 4 8Gb.

Each service are working properly. I can connect to Grafana (`localhost:3000`) and see node_exporter data. I can connect to loki itself and see the metrics (`localhost:3100/metrics`), and I can also connect to promtail (`localhost:9080/targets`).

On Grafana, I tried pointing loki to `10.88.0.1:3100/metrics` (since Grafana is a docker container, I have to use `10.88.0.1` to connect to the host) but I get a new error `Unable to fetch labels from Loki (Failed to call resource), please check the server logs for more details`

Here is what I get from the logs for that error:

```
logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin t=2023-02-12T13:21:35.204508553Z level=error msg="Failed to call resource" error="404 page not found\n" traceID=
logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin t=2023-02-12T13:21:35.204758623Z level=error msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/api/datasources/2/resources/labels status=500 remote_addr=192.168.1.20 time_ms=7 duration=7.563973ms size=51 referer=http://raspberry.local:3000/datasources/edit/sgEZvn14k handler=/api/datasources/:id/resources/*
```

It's weird because without the `/metrics` Grafana does find loki.

I'm using ansible to provision my rasp :

```yml
- name: Grafana - Run container using podman
  containers.podman.podman_container:
      name: grafana
      image: grafana/grafana-oss:latest
      state: started
      recreate: true
      restart_policy: on-failure
      ports: "3000:3000"
      memory: "2048m"
      net:
          - host
      volume:
          - "grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana"

- name: Loki - Run container using podman
  containers.podman.podman_container:
      name: loki
      image: grafana/loki:latest
      state: started
      recreate: true
      restart_policy: on-failure
      ports: "3100:3100"
      memory: "2048m"
      net:
          - host
      volume:
          - "loki-storage:/loki"

- name: Promtail - Run container using podman
  containers.podman.podman_container:
      name: promtail
      image: grafana/promtail:latest
      state: started
      recreate: true
      restart_policy: on-failure
      ports:
          - "9080:9080"
          - "1514:1514"
      memory: "2048m"
      net:
          - host
      volume:
          - "{{ lokiData }}/promtail.yml:/etc/promtail/promtail-config.yml"
      command: -config.file=/etc/promtail/promtail-config.yml
```

My promtail config:

```yml
server:
    http_listen_port: 9080
    grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
    filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:
    - url: http://10.88.0.1:3100/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:
    - job_name: syslog
      syslog:
        listen_address: 0.0.0.0:1514
        labels:
          job: "syslog"
      relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: ['__syslog_message_hostname']
          target_label: 'host'
```

my loki config:

```yml
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100

common:
  path_prefix: /loki
  storage:
    filesystem:
      chunks_directory: /loki/chunks
      rules_directory: /loki/rules
  replication_factor: 1
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-10-24
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h

ruler:
  alertmanager_url: http://localhost:9093
```

I really don't know what to do now, I'm new to Grafana, so maybe I'm missing something. I googled the error, but I found nothing interesting (mainly config mistakes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the journal/syslogs volumes. In fact, everything was working, but promtail had no data to send. Make sure to read the `positions.yaml` file (located by promtail's config).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).